# groovy 'switch' vs. 'if' performance

Tags: performance, groovy, switch-statement

I know that in Java the *switch* statement shouldn't be used when you have few cases, and in this case it's better use an `if else if`.

Is it true also for groovy?

Which is more performant between these two code?

```
myBeans.each{
    switch it.name
    case 'aValue':
        //some operation
    case 'anotherValue:
        //other operations
}
```

or:

```
myBeans.each{
    if(it.name == 'aValue'){
        //some operation
    }
    else if (it.name =='anotherValue){
        //other operations
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a real concern or just a curiosity? It is unlikely this would be the performance bottleneck anywhere in a real application. If you're really curious, why don't you just run some tests and find out?

Comment: It was just curiosity to know what happen inside the JVM when I use the _switch_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Java, "switch" is more effient than serial if blocks because the compiler generates a [tableswitch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.tableswitch) instruction where the target can be determined from a jump table.

In Groovy, switch is not restricted to integer values and has a lot of additional semantics, so the compiler cannot use that facility. The compiler generates a series of comparisons, just like it would do for serial if blocks.

However, `ScriptBytecodeAdapter.isCase(switchValue, caseExpression)` is called for each comparison. This is always a dynamic method call to an `isCase` method on the caseExpression object. That call is potentially more expensive than `ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(left, right)` which is called for an if comparison.

So in Groovy, switch is generally more expensive than serial if blocks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know what changes about this in Groovy 2.0 using static compilation?

Comment: Interesting question, I just checked it. As I expected, it does not change the calls into ScriptBytecodeAdapter. So although @CompileStatic forces static method invocations in the selected method, "switch" and "if" still pull in dynamic method calls via ScriptBytecodeAdapter.

Comment: I wonder if this isn't a place for possible speed optimization?

Comment: I guess this would be rather difficult without changing the semantics of switch and equals.